# How to cp multiple file extensions?

Tags: bash, regex, cp

How do I cp multiple file extensions, like png, jpg and tif files?  I tried:

```
$cp ./*.(jpg|png|tif) ../output/
>bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(`
$cp ./01_reliefs/*.\(jpg\|png\|tif\) ../output/
>cp: cannot stat ‘./01_reliefs/*.(jpg|png|tif)’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: your glob is shell dependent.  What shell are you using? parenthesis like those are not glob metacharacters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), like -

```
$cp ./01_reliefs/*.\{jpg,png,tif} ../output/
```

Comment: `cp ./01_reliefs/*.{a,b,c}` : comma ! Link is right but example is to fix. Then I validate the answer :)

Comment: @Hugolpz this is the correct one?

Comment: yes, the one I provided is the correct one.